# Save files in .jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a couple files I want to include in my .jar for a game server. The files, a SQLite database and an icon, work properly when and only when I put them in the Eclipse project folder and run it straight from Eclipse. As I want this to be distributable to end-users easily, how can I include these files and use them at runtime? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to update that SQLite database at runtime or is it purely static data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing files from within a jar file can be tricky depending on the code that's using them. If the code is written to open a file from the file system, you have to extract it. If your Java code opens it with Class.getResourceAsStream(), it can be read from within the jar. You mentioned an icon and SQLite. I would guess you need to extract those files. I've done this with the maven-dependency-plugin and unpack when using maven. "jar xf foo.jar icon.gif" works too.